# python にて moduleをimportする際、メモリを節約するオプションや方法はありますか？

Tags: python, linux, import, memory

pandasなどメモリ使用量の多いmoduleをimportする際に、メモリを節約できるオプション・方法をご存じでしたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 汎用的な物は無さそうですね。[pythonで機能別にimportしたほうが実行速度やメモリ使用量が改善されますか？](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11217034576) あるとしても個々のモジュールやパッケージに依存するのでは？

Comment: [XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/xy-問題-とは何ですか)のように見えるけど
どんな理由があって「メモリを節約」になったのでしょう？
そのままでは漠然としていて回答しにくいかも。
pandasで大量のデータを扱う場合なら一部ずつ処理する機能あるし,
(例えば)マイクロコントローラーで Python使うなら MicroPython使う方法も (たぶんフットプリント小さいはず)